# Pytesseract: Windows Error[Error 2] "System cannot find specied file" on calling tesseract OCR

Tags: python, tesseract, python-tesseract

I am trying to make tesseract OCR work through Anaconda based on Python 2.7.
After various changes suggested about the process, this is the final code written here.

```
> import os 

> from PIL import * 

> from PIL import Image 

> from tesseract import *                #different : quantum simulations
> 
> import pytesseract
> 
> print os.getcwd() 

> im = Image.open('D:\File_conv\phototest.tif') #to be sure of path

> im.load() 

> print im
> text = pytesseract.image_to_string(im)       #Generates error
> import pytesseract
> print(pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open(
> 'D:/File_conv/phototest.tif')))                #
> print(pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open('test-european.jpg'),
> lang='fra'))                                  #Same error
```

The call to image_to_string generates Windows Error[Error 2] :

```
> > text = pytesseract.image_to_string(im)
> >Traceback (most recent call last):
> 
>   File "<ipython-input-92-1f75dd6f29f3>", line 1, in <module>
>     text = pytesseract.image_to_string(im)
> 
>   File "C:\Program Files
> (x86)\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pytesseract\pytesseract.py", line
> 161, in image_to_string
>     boxes=boxes,
> 
>   File "C:\Program Files
> (x86)\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pytesseract\pytesseract.py", line
> 94, in run_tesseract
>     proc = subprocess.Popen(command,
> 
>   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Anaconda2\lib\subprocess.py", line 711,
> in __init__
>     errread, errwrite)
> 
>   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Anaconda2\lib\subprocess.py", line 959,
> in _execute_child
>     startupinfo)
> 
> WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

I've tried all I could find. I'm on windows and conda could not find the distribution so I manually extracted pytesser to Anaconda2\Lib, modified the **init.py** to point to the tesseract 3.02 installation
It gave the same error as this. I then tried pytesseract which I could find through

```
>pip install pytesseract
```

The system variable TESSDATA_PREFIX and pointer variable image_to_string points correctly:

```
> C:\Program Files (x86)\Tesseract-OCR
```

I cannot figure out which address reference is going wrong.

---

Edit: The same error appears on `print command`:

```
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pytesseract\pytesseract.py", line 94, in run_tesseract
    print command

  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Anaconda2\lib\subprocess.py", line 711, in __init__
    errread,

  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Anaconda2\lib\subprocess.py", line 959, in _execute_child
    env,

WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

The `command` object is defined in the function below. The`print` statements added to for value check did not show up in the console before the error, and the error propagates at `if config:`

```
    def run_tesseract(input_filename, output_filename_base, lang=None, boxes=False, config=None):
    '''
    runs the command:
        `tesseract_cmd` `input_filename` `output_filename_base`

    returns the exit status of tesseract, as well as tesseract's stderr output

    '''
    print tesseract_cmd
    print input_filename
    print output_filename_base
    command = [tesseract_cmd, input_filename, output_filename_base]

    print config
    if lang is not None:
        command += ['-l', lang]

    if boxes:
        command += ['batch.nochop', 'makebox']

    if config:
        command += shlex.split(config)

    print command
    proc = subprocess.Popen(command,
            stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
    return (proc.wait(), proc.stderr.read())
```

Comment: If you want to find out which exe file is called, simply put a `print command` right before the call to subprocess in *pytesseract.py*. That will help you debug.

Comment: Your prints didn't work, your Python is either using a different pytesseract installation or there is still an old `pytesseract.pyc`. You can see it on the exact identical traceback, the error should be moved by like 4 lines (instead of it beeing at `if config` which makes zero sense).

Answer (score -2):

I had the same problem, this is what I did:

[image: Console]